# Is TInterfacedObject autofree thread safe in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, thread-safety, tinterfacedobject

Is `TInterfacedObject._Release` and `TInterfacedObject._AddRef` thread safe?
I can see `FRefCount` is thread safe, but `Destroy` is not protected by locks or something else.

```pascal
function TInterfacedObject._Release: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedDecrement(FRefCount);
  if Result = 0 then
    Destroy;
end;
```

Could different thread execute `Destroy` at the same time causing a race condition?

Comment: The whole point is that you don't call destroy because you work with the interface rather than the object.

Comment: I know that I cannot call Destroy directly. If one thread checking Result is 0 and try to free, while another thread add ref? Could it happen?

Comment: If result reaches zero then nothing can have a reference any more

Comment: Even in multi-thread environment?

Comment: @qgi yes, even in multi-thread. If the refcount falls to 0, it means there are NO REFERENCES WHATSOEVER to the object. If a thread is trying to increment the refcount, there must have been an existing reference to the object to begin with, so the refcount should not fall to 0 while the thread is incrementing the refcount. Unless you are doing something unusual, like passing around references without refcounting them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementation of reference counting methods in `TInterfacedObject` is thread safe as reference count is incremented and decremented atomically.

When reference count of object instance reaches zero in `_Release` method, that means there is no longer any other strong reference to that object and destroying the object will be thread-safe.

Similarly when you look at `_AddRef` method, when you already have a strong reference to an object, taking another strong reference from it will also be thread-safe.

However, that is not the whole story and there are other things that need to be taken in consideration when handling reference counted instances across multiple threads.

- reference assignment is not thread-safe - you cannot have a variable and write to it from multiple threads in thread-safe manner without using additional access protection mechanisms that will ensure only single thread has access to that reference at a time, like locks.
- taking strong reference from weak reference is not thread-safe - if thread only has a weak reference to some reference counted instance then you cannot assign that weak reference to a strong one in thread-safe manner